# SwiftUI error with ForEach within List: Cannot invoke initializer for type 'List' with an argument list of type '(@escaping () ... (see code)

Tags: core-data, swiftui, swiftui-list

I am trying to have a simple ForEach within a List (and have done this in another Project), but in this project I am getting the below mentioned error?  How could I fix?

**Error**

*Cannot invoke initializer for type 'List' with an argument list of type '(@escaping () -> ForEach, Int64, Text>)'*

**Code**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @FetchRequest(fetchRequest: GCList.allListFetchRequest()) var gcLists: FetchedResults<GCList>

    var body : some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {     // <=== ERROR IS MARKED HERE IN XCODE
                ForEach(self.gcLists) { gcList in
                    Text(gcList.title)
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

and

```
extension GCList : Identifiable {
    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<GCList> {
        return NSFetchRequest<GCList>(entityName: "GCList")
    }
    @NSManaged public var id: Int64
    @NSManaged public var title: String
}

extension GCList {
    static func allListFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<GCList> {
        let request: NSFetchRequest<GCList> = GCList.fetchRequest()
        request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "id", ascending: true)]
        return request
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out in Core Data I had an old entity that I had created called "List" that managed to much things up....